# How to escape characters in wildcard in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a htaccess file which is used for earning money by short links, as the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) http://shortlink.com/s/N9IpzM7J?s=$1 [R=301]
```

But with above code, it'll redirect `example.com/https://google.com` to `http://shortlink.com/s/N9IpzM7J?s=https:/google.com` notice it that it lost a slash at `https://`, in my thought, it might be a special character in htaccess but I don't know how to escape it.

So I want to ask how to let the above code works which will redirect `example.com/https://google.com` to `http://shortlink.com/s/N9IpzM7J?s=https://google.com`?

> Because of [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313621/blacklist-the-use-of-common-link-shorteners-in-posts) I replace by link shortening service's url to shortlink.com!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to capture full URI, you should use `RewriteCond` directive.

Apache automatically strips off multiples slashes into a single slash in `RewriteRule` directive.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ http://shortlink.com/s/N9IpzM7J?s=%1 [R=301,L]
```